# ILO/DRAC like device for desktop

Tags: remote-access, desktop, ilo, drac

Does anyone know if there is some price friendly hardware like HP ILO/Dell DRAC for desktop PC (home server)?

I prefer PCI/PCIe form.

All I need is access to COM port and remote power cycle.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you already have the homeserver? If you do not then look closely at the Intel chipsets. Some of them have support for this. Alternetivly you could buy a workstation class motherboard which often allow an Ilo module to be added. Or, as I did, a dell with an enterprise DRAC for home usage.  If you already have the hardware that I do not know of a price friendly solution.

Comment: @Hennes : Thanks for hint, I already have 1U server with Intel D510 ITX form motherboard.Unfortunately it does not have Intel AMT technology.

Answer (score 1):

Look for a managed PDU in your local stores (there are lots of different vendors manufacturing them, APC being the most famous) - this will provide remove power management. As for a serial console, your BMC might already provide that